# Undefined is not a function on a valid function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I'm writing a scraper, as a test I went to on IMDB and tried to get out some actor names from a list
here is a [link](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls000004615/?start=1) to the page.

I'm trying to grab out the name out from the html when I call this function in the console

```
$('.list_item').find('.info a:eq(0)').each(function (){ console.log(this)})
```

The console will log everything in the  tag, however when I try to grab out the html I get an error undefined is not a function.

```
$('.list_item').find('.info a:eq(0)').each(function (){ console.log(this.html())})
```

However if I give their tag an id I can grab it out with

```
$('#testname').html();
```

This grabs out the correct name

Comment: use function(index,elem) and use $(elem).html() -NVM This.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
console.log(this.html());
```

to

```
console.log($(this).html());
```

The method `.html()` expects a jQuery object. You need to wrap `this` -> `$(this)`.

Answer (score 3):

`html` is a jQuery method, DOM only knows about the `innerHTML` **property**.
So you either need to wrap `this` in a jQuery set or use the innerHTML property there.